# Detect if my application is being executed from the users directory

Tags: c#, directory, detect

I need to detect if my application is being executed from the `users` directory.
For example `c:/users` on **Windows7**.

But i need it to work on all Windows versions.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the directory of the current application as follows:

```
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

You then need a string compare to see to check if the path startswith:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
```

Or which ever location you want to test against, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) for list os special folders. These resolve appropriately under each OS version.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool isUsersPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.StartsWith(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile))
```